# Using modal within a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, ionic-framework, ionic2, formbuilder

I would like to use a modal in my form. I am aware that I should add

```
static get parameters(){
        return [[NavController],[ViewController],[NavParams]];
      };
```

How ever when I add this, to my form class, I get an error, "TypeError: formBuilder.group is not a function"

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks,
Andrew